# Неявное преобразование типов

Tags: c++, типы-данных, преобразование, warning

```
class A;
class B
{
    public:
        B (A *p):y(p) {}
        ~B() {delete y;} 
        operator A const& () const {return *y;}
        operator A& () {return *y;}
    private:
        A *y;
};
class A
{
    public:
        A(int ax):x(ax) {}
        A* Clone() const 
        {
            return new A(x);
        } 
        B operator + (A const &v2) const
        {
            A *pv=v2.Clone();
            pv->x+=x;
            return B(pv);
        }
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, A const &v)
        {
            os << x;
            return os; 
        }
    protected:
        int x;
};
int main()
{
    A v(4),v1(5);
    cout << v+v1; // <----------
}
```

Почему не работает указанная инструкция, а также почему появляется предупреждение???

> [Warning] possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
>   [enabled by default]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В точке, где происходит компиляция `~B()`, не видно *полного* определения `A`. Поэтому компилятор не может точно определить, что именно он должен делать при `delete`.

Попробуйте разбить проект на части: определения классов отдельно, реализация — отдельно. Таким образом вы сможете компилировать деструктор `B` в .cpp, включив header с полным определением `A`.

---

По поводу второй части, у меня gcc откомпилировал, если вынести `friend ostream& operator <<` за пределы класса: http://ideone.com/SV56y2

Comment: Ок, а почему не работает преобразование типов?

Comment: Ошибка, которую вы упоминаете в вопроск, вовсе не о преобразовании типов, она о деструкторе.

Comment: У меня 2 вопроса, если вы не заметили

Comment: @EgoR: А вы по первому всё исправили?

Comment: аууууууууууууууууу

Comment: @EgoR: Да-да, вы хотели что-то переспросить?

Comment: О_О вынес за пределы класса тоже откомпилировало, почему так???

Comment: @EgoR: Покамест не знаю, расследую.

Comment: @EgoR: Судя по всему, вот ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/476777/276994

Comment: p.s. вынес реализацию деструктора за оба класса, теперь всё ок), но это понятно из вашего ответа

Comment: хм, не совсем понял, как это относится к моему вопросу

Comment: @EgoR: Там написано: «The function [...] will not be visible unless you call operator<< with a Matrix object which will make argument dependent lookup find that operator definition». Судя по всему, это значит, что inline-функция будет принята в рассмотрение только если в выборе функции принимает участие тип `A`. ([Argument-dependent lookup.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)) В вашем случае так есть лишь тип `B`, и цепочка не выстраивается. (А вот если сделать явный каст в `A`, то `A` появляется в цепочке, и она достраивается.)

Comment: ага, что-то чересчур хитро даже для c++. Кстати, другие операторы (=,+-*/) работают без вынесения

Comment: @EgoR: Хе :) Тут были каверзные вопросы по поводу C++, там всё не просто сложно, а очень сложно.